# Modifying a projection ArcMap 10.0 Arcpy

Tags: arcmap, arcpy, geoprocessing, coordinate-system

I have the need to project data from wgs84 to UTM 15N NAD1927 FOOT_US.

I would like to have arcpy do this for me.  I can project the data using one of ArcMaps predifined prj files in the Coordinates folder..but how would I do the "Modify" piece?

UTM 15N NAD1927 is defined in the prj file as "Meters" but I would like to do the arcpy.project_management using a prj file that has been modified either in ArcMap and then saved to disc or my another method...

I found this but am a little unsure.

Thanks for any insight or solution to using a modified prj file when doing a arcpy.project_management on shapefiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use the NAD27 BLM 15N definition. It's really UTM, but using the US survey Foot.

Comment: Perfect...mkennedy...I recently found a pdf of a talk I think you did on coordinate systems for esri.  Do you know where I could find that in video or audio?  Thanks again.

Comment: When I use the NAD27 BLM 15N prj from the projected>>UTM>>north america>> and go from WGS84 to that..using the NAD_27_To_WGS_84_1 transformation..my resulting shapefile doesn't line up with the wgs84 data.

Comment: @justin, see answer on your other question. Check the proceedings for Esri Developer Summit. I think those videos are posted. The User Conference ones are ppt only.